# Generate a form in PHP (or jQuery) from a JSON file

Tags: php, javascript, carousel

I'm writing a plugin for a CMS to insert an image slider into a page, with the user able to chose a number of options. What I would like is to have the code for the image selection and the image order to be seperated from the JS plugin and CSS that actually transforms the data into the slider. In other words, I want to have one section that always stays the same for all my projects and be able to easily swap JS plugins and/or the style of this plugin.

I would like to be able to create a JSON config file with the options found in whatever plugin I want to use the for slider. Some options I will want to chose myself and others I want in a form for the user to chose.

I'll most likely use form2js to save the data once the form is filled out. However, unless I misunderstood, js2form is about filling in a form rather than generating one.

Is there a plugin in PHP or jQuery out there that converts JSON into forms?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to add the code that you've already written :)

Comment: There is a plugin for jQuery called deserialize that you can find here: https://github.com/dejw/jquery.deserialize, maybe that can help?